# Simulating 1K web clients with different mac addresses as sources

Tags: python, linux, simulation, eventlet

I have the following need:

- Simulate 1K (or more) web clients (i.e., http requests) to an ip address.
- Each client has to use  a different mac as source.
- Solution has to be somewhat realistic, i.e., i am hoping to get (under fundamental limits) maximum simultaneous requests from this clients.
- All this in the same machine
- Using linux.

My Question: How can I do this maximising the number of users and requests per second?

I am quite certain (99% :)) of what I am doing. I really need these requests to be send with a different mac address as source since it is a special use case based on OpenFlow switches. But it is irrelevant to expand this scenario into the question.

P.S. 
I am currently working in python using the [Eventlet Networking Library](http://eventlet.net/). Python/Eventlet is not a requirement, but I include it here since i have a certain urgency and a fast implementation/modification of my code would be beneficial. I was thinking that maybe i could associate virtual interfaces with different mac addresses but i am lacking a way to specify the request interface.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test here? MAC addresses aren't usually visible (or meaningful!) to web servers, so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @duskwuff: I assumed he was testing something like a BIG-IP load balancer that discriminates based on which of its local routers the requests are coming over. But now that I think about it, that's a pretty big assumption based on the actual question…

Comment: I am testing a load balancer and device manager application on an openflow controller. I am quite certain that i need to have different mac addresses (and that the ip address is in fact irrelevant). I did not want to overcomplicate the question.

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking that maybe i could associate virtual interfaces with different mac addresses but i am lacking a way to specify the request interface.

If you mean create 1000 virtual interfaces all bound to a single real interface, each with a different fake MAC address, yes, you could do that.

As far as I know, you can't easily give a specific interface to `eventlet.connect` without digging deep into `libevent` underneath. But you *can* give a local address (IP, port) very easily. [`eventlet.connect`](http://eventlet.net/doc/basic_usage.html#eventlet.connect) takes a `bind` parameter, that takes a local address and binds to it.

So, if you just give a different IP address to each virtual interface, and bridge them all through your real interface, that should be all you need.

I'm not entirely sure how *well* this will work, but it should *work*. Try it and see.

There is one obvious downside: You need 1000 routable IP addresses. But assuming you're behind a NAT which you control, that's easy—e.g., 10.0.xy.1zw.

If you're not behind a NAT which you control, just throw one up. You can even run it on the same machine, on the real interface, and just make it a router for the virtual interfaces instead of a bridge.

But, once you're doing that… you may not *need* 1000 virtual interfaces, or do anything at all in your `eventlet` code. If you just configure the NAT to randomize MAC addresses, you may be done. I'm not positive about this; it may try to be smart and treat multiple connections within a short span to the same (host, port) as the same connection for routing, which will get in your way here. But again, try it and see.

Either way, of course, the server will see them as 1000 clients coming from the same NAT router. There's no way around this (unless you actually have 1000 addresses at different parts of the internet) short of spoofing. But, unless you're trying to actually fool some logic in the server, rather than just simulate some behavior, that shouldn't make any difference.

Meanwhile, keep in mind that in real life, the web server's host will only be seeing the MAC addresses of the router(s) it connects to the internet over, and the web server software won't see anything at all, so… I've had to make some assumptions about what you might possibly be trying to test, and I may well have gone way off in the wrong direction. If so, you may want to describe your use case a little better.